# How to disable multiple logins for same user in spring security + spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have the below spring configuration :-

```
      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
        {
            http
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, 
             authException) ->

          response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED))
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, 
           "/api/v2/customers/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, 
           "/oauth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/saml/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, 
          "/api/internal/v2/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
            .sessionRegistry(SR);
}
```

I was expecting sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1) to disable multiple login for the same user. It is working, but first user logout the application, so i am trying login in another browser but it showing This account is already using by someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. you are not clearing/ closing the previous session properly.

```
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/expired").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .expiredUrl("/expired")
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
}


@Bean
public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
    SessionRegistry sessionRegistry = new SessionRegistryImpl();
    return sessionRegistry;
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}

// Register HttpSessionEventPublisher
@Bean
public static ServletListenerRegistrationBean httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
}
}
```

Missing is **.expiredUrl("/expired").maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                    .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());**